# Modular Module? Require parts of module in parent

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Writing a node.js module, and wanting to try and break up my code/keep it neat.

Essentially, what I want is to have a seperate file/folder for each part of the module (authentication, users, etc), and require them all from a parent package, which will then be exposed.

For example, a file structure of:

```
index.js
auth.js
users.js
```

and inside of `index.js`, have:

```
module.exports = {
    some_variable : 1,
    authentication_variable : '',
    auth : require('./auth'),
    users : require('./users')
}
```

I then want `some_variable` accessible from within each of the packages, and `users` to be able to reference `auth`, and vice-versa, and have `authentication_variable` set by `auth`.

Essentially, I want them to be in a class, but because it'll be used in multiple routes in an Express app, I want it to retain the variables/state it had when required in the main file.

I can do this if I keep it all in the same file, but less sure how to do it, because when I require the file, it doesn't have access to it's parent's scope.

What I have so far, as a MWE:

```
module.exports = x = {
    globals : {
        id : 123456
    },
    auth : {
        setId : function(id){
            x.globals.id = id;
        },
        getAuthToken : function(){
            return x.globals.id;
        }
    },
    users : {
        doThing : function(name, id){
            x.auth.setId(id);
            console.log(x.auth.getAuthToken === id); // true
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried the suggestion below, and it doesn't work.  I can't have sub-functions inside of the other module that still var access to the largest scope.

Ideally, I'd like a way to have, all inside a package, `test-package`:

```
index.js
module.exports = {
    test : function(){
        console.log(this); // shows this entire object {test : function, auth: function}
    },
    auth : require('./auth')
}

auth.js
module.exports = {
    check : function(){
        console.log(this); // shows {test : function, auth : function}
    }
}
```

then, inside a separate project

```
var my_mod = require('test-package');
my_mod.test(); // shows as before
my_mod.auth.check(); // shows same
```

If that's not possible, at the very least a way to have the entire `index.js` module accessible from within `auth.js`.

Comment: Sometimes it helps to split up the module.exports into multiple statements. (like module.exports.config = 123)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `this` keyword:

**index.js**:

```
require('./module').auth();
```

**module.js**:

```
module.exports = {
  some_var: 1,
  auth: require('./auth'),
  user: require('./user')
}
```

**auth.js**:

```
module.exports = function() {
  console.log(this);
  this.some_var = 10;
  this.user();
}
```

**user.js**:

```
module.exports = function() {
  console.log(this);
}
```

Comment: But will `this` not refer to the function call? I tried to use this, but if I'm inside of `auth.js`, then surely `this.some_var` will not give me the same `some_var` as Ive got in `index.js`?  Also, if auth needs to be more than one function? What if auth is a whole set of functions relating to auth, and not just exporting one function?